# Issue in importing excel data in access if worksheet contains dropdown list

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007, import-from-excel

I have created an excel worksheet in a such way that the user can insert some rows (max 100).

The value of some fields are chosen from a dropdown list.

I put the formula on all 100 rows.

The problem is that the data are not imported in access, if the user inserts less of 100 rows. In this case the data are imported only if I delete the formula for the dropdown list from the remaining rows.

To import excel data in access I use:

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet [Transfer Type], [Spreadsheet Type], [Table Name], [File Name], [Has Field Names], [Range]
```

How could I resolve this issue?

**EDIT**

After the Remou's answer, I tried with:

```
Private Sub import_Click()

Dim openDialog As FileDialog
Dim FileChosen As Integer

Set openDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
On Error GoTo DoNothing
With openDialog
  .title = "Import"
  .AllowMultiSelect = False
  .Show
End With

filename = openDialog.SelectedItems.Item(1)

Dim xl As Excel.Application
Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
Dim rng As Excel.Range

Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xl.Visible = True
Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(nomeFile)

c = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("1:1").end(-4161).Address
r = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").end(-4121).Row

ImportRange = "Sheet1!" & "A1:" _
   & Replace(Mid(c, 1, InStrRev(c, "$")) & r, "$", "")

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, _
"ImportTable", filename, True, ImportRange

DoNothing:
    If Err.Number = cdlCANCEL Then
    End If

End Sub
```

but I've a debug error on **Dim xl As Excel.Application**

Comment: I did not find that this was the case in an example I tested. All rows where imported, although some of them were blank. did you use ActiveX or a forms dropdown? What is the formula you used.

Comment: @Remou: I use the data validation, list type. So, for example, in a cell the user can insert the value "valueA" or "valueB" (dropdown list). This data validation is used for all the 100 cells in the same column. If the user insert less of 100 rows, the vba import (called when the user clicks on a mask button, in access, and after choosing the excel file to import) doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOTE Having tested with Excel dropdowns and validation dropdowns, I find I do not have any problems importing data with validated cells or dropdowns in unused ranges, other than those rows are imported, even though all other cells are empty. The problem may be with data types and importing into an existing table. You may have to import to a scratch table and then append.

I suggest you use automation to get the used range and add that as the range to import.

This sample code uses late binding. You can add a reference to the Microsoft Excel x.x Object Library, so I have kept the various definitions, but late binding is best if you are using the code on more than one PC.

```
Dim xl As Object ''Excel.Application
Dim wb As Object ''Excel.Workbook
Dim rng As Object ''Excel.Range

Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xl.Visible = True
Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Open("z:\docs\test.xlsx")

'Choosing a column that is fully filled on sheet5
'xldown=-4121,xltoright=-4161
c = wb.Worksheets("Sheet5").Range("1:1").end(-4161).Address
r = wb.Worksheets("Sheet5").Range("A:A").end(-4121).Row

ImportRange = "Sheet5!" & "A1:" _
    & Replace(Mid(c, 1, InStrRev(c, "$")) & r, "$", "")

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, _
    "ImportSheet2", "Z:\Docs\csharp.xlsm", True, ImportRange
```

Comment: how could I get the used range, after the user chooses the excel file to import?

Comment: I obtain an error on Dim xl As Excel.Application (I edited my question with the code I use).

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to remove the definitions. The usual rule is develop with early binding, distribute with late binding.

Comment: Don't worry :) Thank you. Now it works. Is there a way to do the same thing without opening the excel file?

Comment: Try using transferspreadsheet with the name of a new table and see if the data transfers, if it does, it may be possible to import to a new table and then append to your existing table. If it does not work, you could also try ADO or a query. You could even mix and match. get a count of used rows with ado or a query and use that to create the range. As an aside, you only need the Excel file visible to develop and troubleshoot,.

Comment: I don't understand very well. I would that when the user chooses the excel file to import, the file isn't displayed on the screen, but only imported. The data transfer works also if the transferspreadsheet uses the name of a new table, but how is it tied to the fact that file opening?